# SQLiteException: no such table: When Table Exsists

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I have a simple sqlite database file, with three tables. I connect with no issues, and can query from two of the tables with no issues. When I try to query the third table, I receive an SQLiteException, stating that the table doesnt exsist. When I run the `sqlite3` command from the command line, and execute the same query, I have no such issues, and the table, does indeed exsist.

sqlite>.tables : limits       protections  rights

sqlite> .schema rights
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'rights' (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,chest INTEGER,entity TEXT,rights INTEGER,type INTEGER);
CREATE INDEX in3 ON `rights` (chest, entity);

## Methods Ive Tried:

```
PreparedStatement localPreparedStatement = this.connection.prepareStatement("SELECT entity FROM rights WHERE chest = ?");
            localPreparedStatement.setInt(1, paramInt);
            ResultSet localResultSet = localPreparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

And:

```
ResultSet localResultSet = this.connection.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT entity FROM 'rights' WHERE chest = " + Integer.toString(paramInt));
```

I have tried different combinations of single quotes, no quotes, tick marks, no tick marks, thinking that maybe the query is formatted wrong but I am simply at a loss. Any constructive help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I cannot use double quotes as the comments suggest because I use them for my SQL string.

Comment: The second query is categorically wrong; table names should _not_ be in single quotes.  The first prepared statement should be working.  Are you certain that the table really does exist?

Comment: You need to use double quotes to quote column and table names, not single.